# Facebook SDK: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _

Tags: javascript, html, json, facebook

I have the following index.html: http://jsfiddle.net/fxyfwv8L/
Notice that I use the Facebook SDK initialization along with the [jQuery Face Detection](https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection) one. For some reason, these two are conflicting and throw some exceptions such as:

```
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
```

These seem to be generated by a JSON parse(), but I'm not able to understand why and how the FB SDK and jQuery Face Detection conflict.

A live demo is available here: http://stormy-river-6729.herokuapp.com/ (make sure to check the JavaScript console).

Comment: you do know that you will most likely not get read_stream approved, right? just saying, because it´s defined as scope.

Comment: @luschn We took care of that, not a problem ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from line **16512** in the `jquery.facedetection.js` file.

```
var data = "string" == typeof event.data ? JSON.parse(event.data) : event.data, scope = {
```

It happens because `event.data` is set in the format `key=value` and not as a JSON item.

To solve this add code of the format

```
try {
    JSON.parse(event.data)
}
catch (e){
}
```

To catch the parsing error if it happens.